# Mulitple Curl Requests with login from multiple URLS PHP

Tags: php, curl, woocommerce, curl-multi

Having a small issue with this, I have 12 identical curl requests to match an order number typed to get a response. Singularly this works perfectly.

When I try and bring them together - If the 1st URL doesn't have a match move to the second curl request and so on.

The problem I am having is with the logins I think, I am getting nothing back. Im not entirely sure what the best solution would be, whether to run through a set of if/else statements and run the curl request if the last was empty or to run them all at once and display the result from the site that answers!

Here is my current request.

Thanks for your help in advance...

```
$data = array();                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   

$username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$password = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

$ch = curl_init('https://tinywaist.co.uk/wc-api/v2/orders/'.$uksearch.'?consumer_key='.$username.'&consumer_secret='.$password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                                
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))                                                                       
);                                                                                                                   

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$result = json_decode($result, true);



foreach($result as $item) {

    $ordernum = $item['order_number'];
    $date = date('d M Y',strtotime($item['created_at']));
    $firstname = $item['shipping_address']['first_name'];
    $lastname =  $item['shipping_address']['last_name'];
    $company = $item['shipping_address']['company'];
    $ad1 = $item['shipping_address']['address_1'];
    $ad2 = $item['shipping_address']['address_2'];
    $city = $item['shipping_address']['city'];
    $state = $item['shipping_address']['state'];
    $postcode = $item['shipping_address']['postcode'];
    $country = $item['shipping_address']['country'];
    $total = $item['total'];
    $product = $item['line_items'][0]['name'];
    $quantity = $item['line_items'][0]['quantity'];
    $size = $item['line_items'][0]['meta'][0]['value'];
    $prod1 = $item['line_items'][1]['name'];
    $quant1 = $item['line_items'][1]['quantity'];
    $size1 = $item['line_items'][1]['meta'][0]['value'];
    $prod2 = $item['line_items'][2]['name'];
    $quant2 = $item['line_items'][2]['quantity'];
    $size2 = $item['line_items'][2]['meta'][0]['value'];
    $email = $item['billing_address']['email'];
    $status = $item['status'];

    $account = '<a href="http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post='.$ordernum.'&action=edit"  target="_blank">'.$ordernum.'</a>';


    if (!$link = mysql_connect('IP_ADDRESS', 'user', 'pass')) {
        echo 'Could not connect to mysql';
        exit;
    }

    if (!mysql_select_db('DB_Name', $link)) {
        echo 'Could not select database';
        exit;
    }

    $sql    = "SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id = $ordernum AND  meta_key = '_aftership_tracking_number'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $link);



    if (!$result) {
        echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
        echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
        exit;
    }

    $var = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $var = $row['meta_value'] . "\n";
    }


    $arrayuk .= '
            <table class="table table-striped listbox">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Details</th>
            <th>Order Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>       
                <div class="">'.$firstname.' '.$lastname.'</div>
                <p></p>
                <div class="">'.$company.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$ad1.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$ad2.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$city.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$state.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$postcode.'</div>
                <div class="">'.$country.'</div>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="">Number: '.$account.'</div>
                <div class="">Date: '.$date.'</div>
                <p></p>
                <div><a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a></div>
                <p></p>
                <img style="width:25px;" src="../images/flags/uk.png">
                <div class="status">'.$status.'</div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Products</th>
            <th>Tracking</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>       
                <div class=""><b>'.$quantity.'</b> '.$size.' '.$product.'</div>
                <div class=""><b>'.$quant1.'</b> '.$size1.' '.$prod1.'</div>
                <div class=""><b>'.$quant2.'</b> '.$size2.' '.$prod2.' </div>
            </td>
            <td><div class="trackcomplete"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" href="http://track.aftership.com/'.$var.'" target="_blank"><b>'.$var.'</b></a></div></td>


    </tbody>
    </table>';
}


curl_close($ch);
```

If someone could hit me back with an example or a helping hand on how to put the above in to if/else statements bearing in mind it has to work through 12 different requests. I am just not sure if this is right or efficient to do!

Thanks